# Checking agents in a Seize Block

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling, statechart

I wonder how I can trigger a conditional state chart transition (located in an agent, Patient) by checking if a queue (located in Main in a Seize Block) contains patients with a certain characteristic (p_contaminated, boolean parameter here should be true in order for the transition to trigger). I.e., if the queue contains one Patient with p_contaminated = true, the statement should yield true in order to trigger the transition.

[Picture showing the Main chart and the Patient chart. Emphasizing (with red) the mentioned Seize Block and the conditional transition that is wanted to be triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5o4G.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use conditional transitions, ever. They have some quirks (not bugs but easy to work in unexpected ways if you are no crack) and can deteriorate your model performance massively.

You can always replace them with message-based transitions.

In your case, have setup as below:
[image]

every x seconds, leave `Treatment` with a timeout transition. Check your patient queue in `AnyPatientFound` and if true, move to `GoToHallway`, else return to `Treatment`

`AnyPatientFound` should call a boolean function `anyPatientContaimated` that loops through all patients in your queue and returns true if any is contaminated, else false.

Comment: I find it hard to know exactly how much context I should provide in my questions, I'm sorry.

A problem here, with the elegant solution you provided, is that the policy I try to emulate has three criteria; where the abovementioned is one of them. In addition, there needs to be a check that the patient is not contaminated and that there are no other idle Treatment Rooms.

I.e. my conditional transition now contains: !this.p_contaminated & main.TreatmentRooms.idle() == 0 & (is-there-a-contaminated-patient-in-the-queue?)

How would I then add these two checks to your suggested solution?

Comment: About "AnyPatientFound should call a boolean function anyPatientContaimated that loops through all patients in your queue and returns true if any is contaminated, else false."

YES!! This is absolutely what I want to be able to do, but I can't find a way to access and loop trough the agents in a queue in order to make this check. Could you help me on the way?

Comment: Hi, best ask separate new questions to keep things clean here. Do have a look at how this place works and how to ask good questions. You did a good job already but new details or asking for code should be done separately following this guide:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Also, learn here what to exclude/include: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Last, if this helped, upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info :) welcome to SOF

Comment: Thanks for instructive feedback Benjamin!
There are several upvotes that will be activated once my reputation hits 15.